# How to add Cypress "data-cy" to Next.js Link?

Tags: next.js, cypress

This is how I can add `data-cy` if `Link` has an `<a>`. But what if `Link` does not have it?

```js
<Link href="/about/">
    <a data-cy="nav-item">About</a>
</Link>
```

https://imranhsayed.medium.com/using-cypress-with-next-js-for-end-to-end-testing-cypress-nextjs-example-af100609cf16

Comment: Can you even use `<Link>` without `<a>`?

Comment: Yes, you can, .. we are using `span` inside

Comment: Ok, so `<span data-cy="nav-item">`?

Comment: 5 mins google, the only problematic example was a styled component. That would be difficult to add the data attribute to.

Comment: This was the example I couldn't figure out how to add the data attribute to: [If the child is a custom component that wraps an <a> tag](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-custom-component-that-wraps-an-a-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<Link>` will never actually appear in the Clients DOM.

It is 'just' used to let next.js know that you want to have in-app navigation. If you would use the `<a>` alone you would get a full page reload every time you click the link. Read more [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link)

Since Cypress is like a user, actually clicking the `<a>` in the DOM, you don't need to worry about `<Link>`at all in this scenario.